# SQL optimization

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb, query-performance

I am trying to optimaze a query on mysql.

Here is the table structure:

TABLE FILE:

```
id: int(8) primary key auto_increment
filename: varchar(1024)
```

The ideia is to create a navigation struture like a filebrowser.

So the user click on the first folder, and see a list of files and folders where it can click to interact with the file or click in another folder.

Let assume I know the name of the first directory is '/storage/'.

Here is the query I am using the to list the files and folders inside the '/storage/' folder:

```
-- List Files
SELECT FileName,ID
FROM FILE
WHERE SUBSTRING(FileName, 1, 9) = '/storage/'
  AND LOCATE('/', SUBSTRING(FileName, 9+1)) = 0
UNION
-- List folders
SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTRING(FileName, 11+1, LOCATE('/', SUBSTRING(FileName, 9+1)))) AS FileName,
       0 AS ID
FROM FILE
WHERE 
  SUBSTRING(FileName, 1, 9) = '/storage/'
  AND LOCATE('/', SUBSTRING(FileName, 9+1)) > 0
ORDER BY ID, FileName
```

This query is working and list the files and folders:

```
FILENAME                    ID
subdirectory/               0
/storage/test.jpg           123
```

How can I optimize the query to be faster?

I already add index to the filename and id columns, but look like the index is not been used when I use the mysql functions in the query like locate, substring, etc.

My storage has 20T and the query is taking 7 seconds to finish.

**EDITED**

I add another column 'dirpath varchar' where I add the directory which the file is located, and I was able to get 50% improviment.

I created two triggers to populate this column:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_dirpath_INSERT_file
BEFORE INSERT
ON file FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.dirpath = SUBSTR(new.filename, 1, LENGTH(new.filename)-LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(new.filename, '/', -1)));    


CREATE TRIGGER TR_dirpath_UPDATE_file
BEFORE UPDATE
ON file FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.dirpath = SUBSTR(new.filename, 1, LENGTH(new.filename)-LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(new.filename, '/', -1)));
```

The final SQL is:

```
-- List Files
SELECT FileName,ID
FROM FILE
WHERE dirpath = '/storage/'

UNION
-- List folders
SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTRING(FileName, 11+1, LOCATE('/', SUBSTRING(FileName, 9+1)))) AS FileName,
       0 AS ID
FROM FILE
WHERE 
  SUBSTRING(FileName, 1, 9) = '/storage/'
  AND LOCATE('/', SUBSTRING(FileName, 9+1)) > 0
ORDER BY ID, FileName
```

Now I have to find out a way to improve the second part of this SQL ( List Folders ).

Comment: You are right, `mysql` do not use indexes for any function. In case of `SUBSTRING()` the proper index should contain all possible substrings for each string stored in the field. That would drive to the huge overhead for storage and computation and for some cases indexed search would be slower that non-indexed. That is why you have to refactor the database and exclude as possible any functions from JOIN/GROUP/ORDER/WHERE clauses if you need optimization.

Answer (score 0):

A general rule in designing MySQL schemas -- Separate pieces that will need to be split up.  Do this *before* inserting.  You are already seeing how messy it is to split the path from the filename.

When I did a similar database, I chose to have 2 tables:  One for `Directories`, one for `Files`.  `Files` had the `filename` without the path, plus a reference (`dir_id`) to a row in `Directories`.